# Meaning and usage of "perforce"

Tags: usage, word-order

I have been looking up dictionaries & literature to understand the meaning & usage of "perforce". I have some doubts about it.

Take this example:

> Drinking wine is not perforce unhealthy.

> Drinking wine is not unhealthy perforce.

- Should "perforce" go before or after "unhealthy"?
- Does "perforce" mean in this example the same as "necessarily"?

Comment: Yes, it means _necessarily_, and it normally comes before the thing that is said to be necessary (or not, in this case!).

Comment: Please be aware that [*perforce* is a very old-fashioned word and is probably not well-known now.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perforce&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)  You may want to avoid it unless you are trying to write for an audience at a very high reading level.

Comment: @stangdon: It certainly *sounds* "old-fashioned". But as my first chart below shows, 200 years ago it was *very* uncommon (**1000:1**?) compared to near-synonymous ***necessarily***, so it's hardly "early Victorian". But by 100 years ago, the relative frequency had narrowed to **70:1**. Not for the negated version, though.

Comment: perforce is basically Shakespearean and not much used since the 18th century.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented, ***perforce** is a very old-fashioned word*, so you might want to avoid it anyway. But another "usage note" that you probably won't find in dictionaries is that we don't often ***negate*** the term.

[Here's an NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20necessarily%2C%28%28is%20perforce%29*70%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) where I multiplied occurrences of ***is perforce*** by 70 so we can see it on the same usage chart as ***is necessarily*** (which means exactly the same)...

[image]

...and [here's the same NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20not%20necessarily%2C%28%28is%20not%20perforce%29*70%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but with both expressions ***negated***...

[image]

Even when increased by a factor of 70, ***is not perforce*** practically "flatlines" against ***is not necessarily***. So even if you don't want to avoid ***perforce*** completely, you should certainly consider avoiding it in "negating" contexts.

---

As regards the *position*, we normally put the adverb (***perforce, necessarily***, or similar) *immediately after* the copula verb ***is***. It *can* be placed at the end of an utterance (as a "whole sentence adverb"), but that's not common.

Comment: Thank you. What alternative words to "perforce" would you use within the "negating" context of the above example? I am already familiar with "necessarily".

Comment: Why would I (or you) want an "alternative" to ***necessarily***? The reason you should be looking for alternatives to ***perforce*** is obvious (it's old-fashioned, *and* you didn't realise that it's a *particularly* bad choice for negated contexts). But ***necessarily*** is fine. In many contexts, terms like ***definitely, clearly, certainly, undoubtedly, by definition,...*** can be used instead, but it's usually best to find the *right* word for the context, and stick with it. Trying to find synonyms to avoid writing the same word repeatedly is usually characteristic of poor writing style.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Your comment is not very kind. You are questioning his/her comment, you are not answering his/her comment by providing appropriate synonyms because you disagree with his/her request, and you are providing a bunch of adverbs that are not synonymous with necessarily and perforce.

Comment: @jeef: To a first approximation, ***there are no synonyms*** in English. Words with overlapping senses may *look* like synonyms to people who don't have excellent knowledge of the language (such as *learners*) but it's counterproductive to encourage people to think like that.

Comment: I see no problem with the negative form. *Breaking up with your partner does not perforce leave a scar. This is not perforce bad news. Democracy does not perforce enable freedom.*

Comment: @deviza: I never suggested there's any *inherent* problem with negating ***perforce*** (it's not like it's syntactically invalid). But as my charts show, *for whatever reason*, native speakers tend to ***seriously*** avoid it. Obviously If I hadn't already sensed that ***not perforce*** sounded a little "odd", it would never have occurred to investigate usage charts in the first place (there's effectively *zero* chance that anyone would actually be *taught* that).

Comment: Maybe it's an AmE vs. BrE thing?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It does not sound odd to me. There are plenty of examples in American books and newspapers.

Comment: @rajesun: Google Books is dominated by American texts, so even if 100% of all BrE usages were ***is not perforce***, it would still be that same flat line at the bottom of my second chart. But these are *averages* - there will obviously be hundreds of counter-examples to the tens of thousands of "more likely" usages.

Comment: @rajesun: I might as well not have bothered going to all that trouble to clearly illustrate the ***relative frequency*** of ***not perforce*** compared to ***not necessarily***.